# CSS Media queries percentage Explanation

Tags: css, media-queries

I know that this is basic question, but i can't figure this one out. Inside Wordpress theme CSS file I am seeing this code (CSS media queries).

```css
.site-content {
    float: left;
    width: 65.104166667%;
}
```

So my question/s is: Why is width percentage set this way instead of just 65.1% ? 

How did person that coded that site **knew** that width must be **exactly** **65.104166667%** and not **65.104166666%** (what tools did he/she used to get exactly that percentage number)?

And finally what are the **Benefits****/Risks** using this approach?

If someone can point me to right direction by an answer or link I would appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this article on responsive web design: http://alistapart.com/article/fluidgrids

As you can see, there is a basic formula for changing pixel widths (fixed widths) into percentages. If you read the article, you'll see that the formula is:

> > target / context = result

Or in other words:

> > The width (in pixels) you are aiming for, divided by the browser's default font-size (generally 16px) equals the width in ems or percentages.

The reason you divide by the default font-size is the same reason why in science experiments in grade school you need a control substance. A neutral substance with which to compare the rest of the experiments with.

So to get 65.1041...etc, the person divided the width they wanted in pixels and it came to that percentage. Percentages and ems are the units of measurement you want to use in web design to achieve a responsive website. And all it takes is some simple math.

My personal preference is to round to 2-3 decimal places, but it really doesn't matter unless you absolutely have to have *exact* widths. I've recommended that above article countless times on this website, it's really a must-read to any web designer of now.